# Calculadora dentro de un único input

Tags: javascript, html, input

Para comenzar sé que no tiene sentido, usar una operación aritmética dentro de un solo input, pero estoy creando un tipo de Spotlight de Mac en el buscador de mi página, estoy aprendiendo Javascript, gracias aquí he aprendido muchas cosas...

```
document.querySelector('#s-s').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let input = document.querySelector('#s-s').value;
  let result = Function("return " + input)();
  if (result === undefined){result = "";}
  document.getElementById('s-s').value = (result);
});
```

Ese es el script que he creado el problema viene cuando quiero ingreso más de dos dígitos después del operador ejemplo 2+10 no la realiza porque automáticamente toma 2+1; la solución que pense es cambiar el "input" de la funcion por un "change" funciona correcto, PERO como digo al principio es un buscador de mi sitio web; entonces si presione enter me busca una entrada no me realiza la operacion.

Estuve pensando en asignarle una tecla como por ejemplo que escriba 2+10= que cuando escriba el = se realice la operacion pero no tengo nada idea. Gracias de ante mano

```
<form action='/search' id='noop-searchform' method='get'>
                  <input autocomplete="off" id='s-s' name='q' onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;Buscar en sechip.club&quot;;}' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;Buscar en sechip.club&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;}' type='text' value='Buscar en sechip.club'/>
                </form>
```

Aqui esta el HTML

Comment: Puedes compartir tu HTML? No me queda claro el problema viendo el código del input.

Comment: Cuál es el propósito de ```let result = Function("return " + input)();```?

Comment: Recibe los valores de tu input, luego tomalo como cadena y separalos por el operador. Es decir, recibirías "2+10" y tendrias esa variable tipo cadena, la vas a separar buscando el operador "+" (incluso podria ser otro operador)

Comment: Listo ya ahi esta el HTML

Comment: Ya entendí qué estás haciendo con el Function. Creo que lo único que puedes hacer controlar la función con la tecla ```enter``` o ```espacio```. No hay alguna otra manera de que el código sepa cuando ha finalizado el usuario. Otra sería tal vez ponerle un ```timeOut```  a la función para que se ejecute luego de X tiempo y que el usuario tenga tiempo de escribir lo que necesta.

Comment: Con tu ```input``` también das pie a que el usuario haga lo que quiera con tu página de una manera muy sencilla, por ejemplo, pegar en el input: ```document.body.innerHTML += "<h>He hackeado tu pagina</h>";```

Comment: @FranAcuna si eso mismo pero me podrias ayudar como aplicar el timeOut, plis